# POSTGRES jsonb document GIN Indexes are created on what all objects?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am using Postgres DB 13.5. From [pgdocs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-json.html) -

> The technical difference between a jsonb_ops and a jsonb_path_ops GIN
> index is that the former creates independent index items for each key
> and value in the data, while the latter creates index items only for
> each value in the data. Basically, each jsonb_path_ops index item
> is a hash of the value and the key(s) leading to it; for example to
> index {"foo": {"bar": "baz"}}

Understanding the above in detail is important for me coz my jdata (document) is big with many keys and nested objects. Consider  **[my json data](https://jsonformatter.org/42af5d)** that is stored as jsonb in a column named  `jdata` looks like below -

```
{
  "supplier": {
    "id": "3c67b6eb-3b0d-492d-8736-66df107b83b3",
    "customer": {
      "type": "pro",
      "name": "John George",
      "address": [
        {
          "add-id": "098ad4df-2a90-4fda-8f92-dbe8d7196732",
          "addressActive": true,
          "street": "abc street",
          "zip": 94044,
          "staying-since": "long long",
          "accessibility": {
            "traffic": "heavy/congested",
            "bestwaytoreach": {
              "weekdays": {
                "bart/metro/calltrain": true,
                "price": {
                  "off-peak-hours": "affordable",
                  "peak-hours": "high"
                },
                "journey-time": "super-fast"
              }
            },
            "weekends": {
              "byroad": {
                "ok": true,
                "distance": "long",
                "has-tolls": {
                  "true": true,
                  "toll-price": "relatively-high"
                },
                "journey-speed": "fast"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "add-id": "ddd1d2a0-9050-4bcf-a3ad-2e608d65e468",
          "addressActive": true,
          "street": "xyz street",
          "zip": 10001,
          "staying-since": "moved recently",
          "accessibility": {
            "traffic": "heavy/congested",
            "bestwaytoreach": {
              "weekdays": {
                "subway": true,
                "price": {
                  "off-peak-hours": "affordable",
                  "peak-hours": "high"
                },
                "journey-speed": "super-fast"
              }
            },
            "weekends": {
              "byroad": {
                "ok": true,
                "distance": "moderate",
                "tolls": {
                  "has-tolls": true,
                  "toll-price": "relatively-high"
                },
                "journey-time": "super-fast"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "CRAWFORD",
      "emailAddresses": {
        "personal": [
          "johnreplies@jg.com",
          "ursjohn@jg.com",
          "1234@jg.com"
        ],
        "official": [
          {
            "repies-in": "1 day",
            "email": "jg@jg.com"
          },
          {
            "check's regularly": true,
            "repies-in": "1 Hour",
            "email": "jg-watching@jg.com"
          }
        ]
      },
      "cities": [
        "NYC",
        "LA",
        "SF",
        "DC"
      ],
      "splCustFlag": null,
      "isPerson": true,
      "isEntity": false,
      "allowEmailSolicit": "Y",
      "allowPhoneSolicit": "Y",
      "taxPayer": true,
      "suffix": null,
      "title": null,
      "birthDate": "05/10/1993",
      "loyaltyPrograms": null,
      "phoneNumbers-summary": [
        1234567890,
        1234567899,
        1234567898,
        1234567897
      ],
      "phoneNumbers": [
        {
          "description": null,
          "extension": null,
          "number": 1234567890,
          "countryCode": null,
          "type": "Business"
        },
        {
          "description": null,
          "extension": null,
          "number": 1234567899,
          "countryCode": null,
          "type": "Home"
        }
      ],
      "data-privacy": {
        "required": true,
        "laws": [
          "CCPA",
          "GDPR"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Now if I create GIN  `jsonb_ops` index** for jdata column - I want to clarify what all **keys** and **values** will be part of index.
For example - `"staying-since"` is a key nested at below path and it's part of `"address"` **array** too. But it's still a key, thought nested deep in the document. **So will it be part of the index.**

```
{
  "supplier": {
    "customer": {
      "address": [
        {
          "staying-since": "long long" ...
```

And similarly `"long long"` is a value of a deeply nested key. Will it also be indexed.

---

And if GIN `jsonb_path_ops` index is created for jdata column --
Will a hash of **"long long"** value along with the path that leads to it will also be indexed.

```
hash( 
      "supplier": {
        "customer": {
          "address":[{"staying-since": "long long"}]
          }
         }  
     )
```

**will the above also gets index.**

---

I am aware about the [operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/gin-builtin-opclasses.html) that are supported by the GIN index types and am aware about the usage of these operators -

**jsonb_ops**       `?` `?&` `?|` `@>` `@?` `@@`
**jsonb_path_ops**      `@>` `@?` `@@`

Comment: Nesting depth does not matter. Both index types will index *all* objects anywhere in the document. The difference is in *how* they are hashing them, which affects what kinds of operators can use the index. So the real question you should ask yourself is: What queries do you expect to run that will need to use the index?

Comment: "*I am aware about the usage of the supported operators*" - then what is your question?

Comment: -its about on what all objects (keys/values) the indexes will be created. For the default `jsonb_ops`, it looks like the full document will be part of the index(kind of how elastic search does). While for `jsonb_path_ops` it's similar but it's hash of the key/value combination that is indexed. Am I right?

Comment: if you can elaborate as an answer with any additional details etc, that will be wonderful

Comment: This kind of detail is probably addressed by looking at the source code, or by trying and seeing.  Are you concerned about the size of the index or the functionality (which is almost completely encapsulated by the list of operators), or the performance of different functionalities?